# How is the private key used for the keygen HTML element?

Tags: encryption, private-key, html5-keygen

When I use a **keygen** tag the browser generates a key pair. The public key is sent to the server, it creates a certificate and returns this certificate to the browser, but where is a private key and why does the browser seem to store it? Does browser compare private key with public key before accepting certificate? There are another reasons?